# how to position several div tags over each other

Tags: html, css, position

I have a problem with positioning 3 different div tags one over each other.  Originally they suppose to overlap but in reality they are positioned one below each other, which I'm trying to avoid.

Can somebody suggest me how can I position all 3 in one point?

Here is the CSS I' using:

```
#menudiv{
height:225px;
width:900px;
background-image:url(images/menu1.jpg);
}

#menudiv2{
height:225px;
width:900px;
background-image:url(images/menu3.jpg);
visibility:hidden;
}


#menudiv3{
height:225px;
width:900px;
background-image:url(images/menu2.jpg);
visibility:hidden;
 }


#tableMenuDiv{
position:absolute;
width:100px;
height:225px;
left:53px;
top:137px;
 }
```

and here is an html code where I place them in the page:

```
<td width="900px" align="left">

<div id="menudiv"></div>
<div id="menudiv2"></div>
<div id="menudiv3"></div>

<div id="tableMenuDiv">
</td>
```

Comment: `td`? You should remove your `tables` for page layout and replace them with `div`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take the divs out of the normal flow, not set their visibility to hidden. Do so by setting `position: absolute;` on them.

Comment: the thing is I'm playing with the visibility in the forth div where menu is located. Ok let me try to set it with the absolute position

Comment: here's an example for you with absolute positioning http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/ajJJs/